# Display image as popup

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview, uiimageview

I need to display a table formatted data on top of a UIWebView as a modal.  Basically a UIAlertView.  However, I need to display tabular data in this modal, which UIAlertView can't do (that I know of).  I'm thinking to create an image with the textual data in it and display the image in a UIImageView or that within a UIView that can have a button for closing.  Not sure if that can all be made modal.

I see a view can be added as a subview to UIAlertView: http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/03/open-iphone-sdk-building-a-uip.html.  Not sure if Apple will go for that though.

Do these approaches sound feasible or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

there is a very simple way add a table and a uiwebview in a view. set the datasource and delegate of the table.and show the data. or if you want something else...show a picture or explain in more detail.